# rock paper scissors javascript code doesnt work. I made this as my first project and i dont know at all why it doesnt work

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, undefined

```js
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
   
    if (playerSelection == computerSelection) {
        console.log("its a tie")

       } else if (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "paper") {
        return "you lose" 

     } else if (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "scissors") {
        
        return "you win"  

     }  else if (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "scissors") {
        return "you lose" 

     } else if (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "rock") {
        return "you win" 

     } else if (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "rock") {
        return "you lose" 

     } else if (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "paper") {
        return "you win" 
     }    
}
   
let playerSelection = parseInt(prompt("input rock paper or scissors"))
let computerSelection = Math.random();

if (computerSelection < 0.34){
  computerSelection = "rock"
} else if(computerSelection <=0.67){
  computerSelection = "paper"
} else {
  computerSelection = "scissors"
}

console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection))
```

I know its probably not the best method but i thought it should get the job done, any help is useful as i don't know where the mistake can be, thank you. I looked at some other posts but couldn't find the solution. This is my first post so if there is some info missing or something just let me know!

Comment: `parseInt` is for extracting numeric data from a string. Since your input will be words, you have no used for it.

Comment: When dealing with stuff like this, try hard coding variables before using the 'input' variables.

Comment: You could collapse all of the "you lost" tests into a single `else`. If you didn't tie or win, you lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `parseInt` because the user will be entering string data, not numbers.

You also need to move some of your `console.log()` statements around a bit, but other than that, you're good to go!

```js
// No parseInt when the input is strings that need to be strings
let playerSelection = prompt("input rock paper or scissors");
let computerSelection = Math.random();

if (computerSelection < 0.34) {
  computerSelection = "rock"
} else if(computerSelection <=0.67) {
  computerSelection = "paper"
} else {
  computerSelection = "scissors"
}

playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection)

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    // Instead of returning in each branch, just set the value of a string that you can
    // report at the end of the function.
    let result = "";
   
    if (playerSelection == computerSelection) {
       result = "its a tie"
     } else if (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "paper") {
        result = "you lose" 
     } else if (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "scissors") {
        result =  "you win"  
     }  else if (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "scissors") {
        result =  "you lose" 
     } else if (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "rock") {
        result =  "you win" 
     } else if (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "rock") {
        result =  "you lose" 
     } else if (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "paper") {
        reresult = "you win" 
     }
     
     console.log("Compupter picked: " + computerSelection, "You picked " + playerSelection, result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues,

1. not returning when it's tied.
2. converting the prompt into an int.

Try the following

```
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
    return 'its a tie';
  } else if (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
    return 'you lose';
  } else if (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'scissors') {
    return 'you win';
  } else if (playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'scissors') {
    return 'you lose';
  } else if (playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'rock') {
    return 'you win';
  } else if (playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'rock') {
    return 'you lose';
  } else if (playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
    return 'you win';
  }
}

let playerSelection = prompt(`Type 'rock' or 'paper' or 'scissors'`)

let computerSelection = Math.random();
if (computerSelection < 0.34) {
  computerSelection = 'rock';
} else if (computerSelection <= 0.67) { 
  computerSelection = 'paper';
} else {
  computerSelection = 'scissors';
}

console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
```

Comment: PS... 3.339* != 0.3333333333333333

Comment: FYI: every condition in `playRound` returns a value: you can remove all `else` there. [See also](https://developer20.com/elseless/)

Answer (score 0):

It may be an idea to not use all the `if`'s and `else`'s by using a small array with winning combinations, combine the user input with computer input and use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator) to determine the result.

Here's a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of this idea.

It is used in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/scissorspaperrock?file=PlayFactory.js) project.

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function playRound(playerSelection) {
  const choices = [`rock`, `paper`, `scissors`];
  const wins = [`scissorspaper`,`rockscissors`,`paperrock`];
  const computerSelection = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
  const combined = playerSelection + computerSelection;
  const report = `you: ${playerSelection}, computer ${computerSelection}: `
  return wins.find(v => v === combined) 
    ? `${report} you win` : computerSelection === playerSelection
    ? `${report} tie` : `${report} you loose`;
}

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.dataset.rps) {
    return console.log(playRound(evt.target.dataset.rps));
  }
  if (evt.target.dataset.clear) {
    return console.clear();
  }
}
```

```css
span[data-rps] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
span[data-rps]:hover {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 70% !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span data-rps="rock"> rock</span>
  <span data-rps="paper"> paper</span>
  <span data-rps="scissors"> scissors</span>
  <div>
    <button data-clear="1">clear console</button>
  </div>
</div>
```